# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x20) even when NSZombieEnabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, lldb

I am getting a crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on my application, and I enabled the NSZombie on the executable scheme for debugging. I still get this crash even though the NSZombie enabled. The prime suspect is a thread (not the main thread) that causing this error. I am doing some kvo stuff in my code. it seems to come from it. I cannot find where it causes the problem.
here is the backtrace for the thread. Can anyone tell me how to pin point the problem ? any clues or or debugging tips would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** : I tried to run the analyzer and the program just stopped and closed itself while running on the analyzer. No messages nothing... just closed silently and the recording stopped. I am not very good at looking at the analyzer, but can anyone tell me where to look at ?

```
* thread #9: tid = 0x2803, 0x00cfdb3e Foundation`__block_global_4 + 420, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x20)
    frame #0: 0x00cfdb3e Foundation`__block_global_4 + 420
    frame #1: 0x00c5b9d7 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 675
    frame #2: 0x00c5b72e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:usingBlock:] + 63
    frame #3: 0x00cfd994 Foundation`____NSOQDelayedAttachPendingOperations_block_invoke_0 + 98
    frame #4: 0x00c5b9d7 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 675
    frame #5: 0x00c5b72e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:usingBlock:] + 63
    frame #6: 0x00c84e7b Foundation`__NSOQDelayedAttachPendingOperations + 156
    frame #7: 0x01615014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #8: 0x01604fd6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_after_timer_callback + 28
    frame #9: 0x01615014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #10: 0x0160c8b7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 219
    frame #11: 0x01608405 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 322
    frame #12: 0x01606280 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 231
    frame #13: 0x01606450 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    frame #14: 0x995eee12 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 441
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)? That frequently will highlight the line of code that is causing the exception when debugging your app. We can't possibly diagnose the source of the problem without seeing code, but perhaps you can identify the problem yourself with an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Calling a nil block could cause a crash like this. You could look and see if you're potentially passing a nil block to some code that might be calling it. Also, are you sure you're safely handling your KVO observers if the notifications are coming from background threads? Maybe you could post some code that might be involved in this KVO event?

Comment: @Rob: yes, I have enabled all the exception break point in xcode. For me it is showing the disassembly code... that is where it stop with the crash.

Comment: @JesseRusak: I am using all in-place blocks in my application. so I guess there is no invalid blocks.

Comment: @JesseRusak: I have seen the KVO crashes... and I did correct those before... but this one, no clue.

Comment: The analyzer will produce messages in the build results panel, where compiler errors and warnings live.

Comment: Does it happen when u start the application ? May be KVO Things only work after some standard initial work, so it could be your'e "using/activating" it to early with some kind of assignment?

Comment: @JesseRusak: no messages whatsoever :-(

Comment: @DigiMonk: No I am using it way after my app has come onto the screen.

Comment: Ok. Just in case: check for broken bindings that u created within IB, sometimes they get accidentally removed (mis-click or whatever).

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem which also seems to be related to this AFNetworking issue: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1626

Comment: @Koraktor Thanks for sharing. Updating AFNetworking solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's really, really dangerous to use KVO across threads. In this case, it looks like you're modifying a value in thread #9, which is triggering the KVO message there. However, if your observer depends on being in the main thread (e.g., it does anything with the user interface, or it doesn't have protection around any data it accesses), your app will crash.

Have you stepped through the app one line at a time to see which line causes the crash?